# Spring : how to get values from properties file in Model class

Tags: java, spring, properties-file

I am using Spring MVC for project. I have some constant values which is stored in properties file and I want to fetch from properties file. **Question I am unable to fetch values in Model Classes from properties file. It is getting null**.

[image: Project Explorer]

I have set property file location in servlet-context.xml

```
 <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:myproperties.properties" />
```

Now by using **@Value** annotation I inject value from properties file.

```
@Component
class ModelTest {

     @Value("${fname}")
     private String fname;

     // Default Constructor
     public ModelTest(){
          Sysout(fname);      // getting null here
     }

     @PostConstruct
     public void initMembers(){
          Sysout(fname)      // Prints fname value properly    
     }

     public void setFname(String fname){
          this.fname=fname;
     }

     public String getFname(){
          return fname;
     }

     @Override
     public String toString() {
          Sysout(fname);
          return "ModelTest [variableFirst=" + variableFirst + "]"; 
     }
}
```

Here is ServiceTest class.

```
@Service
class ServiceTest(){

    @Value("${fname}")
    private String fname;

    public String printTest(){
         sysout(fname);           // Prints fname value
         return new ModelTest().toString() // Prints null
    }
}
```

Here is ControllerHome Class :

```
@Controller
public class ControllerHome {

     @Value("${fname}")
     private String fname;

     @Autowired
     private ServiceTest service;

     @RequestMapping("/")
     public @ResponseBody String printData(){
          sysout(fname);           // Prints fname value
          return service.printTest();  // Print null
     }
}
```

**In model class fname is getting null while In controller and service class value is coming properly.**

is anyone face such issue?

Comment: Is `ModelTest` your model class ? Is there any other annotations like @Entity... ?

Comment: yes It is dummy model class. and no there is no @entity annotation.

Comment: what is component scanning package path ? it should be *.alert

Comment: <context:component-scan base-package="com.alert />

Comment: @MiteshParmar sorry I dont think so there will any issue regarding component scan. In controllerHome, ServiceTest class it is working excellent. but In model class only, its not working, thats my question. base-package is same as you written.

Comment: dont' you need to use  <util:properties location="classpath:myproperties.properties"/>  instead of property-placeholder (see e.g.http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-is-not-working-in-value/)

Comment: I tried with this <util:properties id="property" location="classpath:myproperties.properties"/> but its printing like ${fname} & ${lname}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say model class, do you mean the value passed to a controller method indicated by `@ModelAttribute`?

If so, that class is created by ordinary constructor invocation through reflection. It is not a spring bean, and thus `@Value` does nothing.

Addressing your edit, I think there is some fundamental misunderstanding about how Spring works.

```
@Service
class ServiceTest(){

    @Value("${fname}")
    private String fname;

    public String printTest(){
        sysout(fname);           // Prints fname value
        // Calling new here means Spring does nothing
        // ModelTest is not a Spring bean
        // `@Component`, `@PostConstruct` and `@Value` in ModelTest mean nothing.
        return new ModelTest().toString() // Prints null
    }
}
```

Instead, you have to do something like this:

```
@Service
class ServiceTest(){

    @Value("${fname}")
    private String fname;

    @Autowired
    private ModelTest modelTest;

    public String printTest(){
        sysout(fname);           // Prints fname value
        // modelTest is now a Spring bean
        return modelTest.toString() // Should not print null
    }
}
```

Now, Spring will create `ModelTest`, and `@Component`, `@PostConstruct` and `@Value` will be honored by Spring.

However, `@Component` by itself has a default singleton scope. So, you will have the same `modelTest` always.

So, you have to do something like this:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
class ModelTest {
    // ...
}
```

Now, while the `modelTest` reference in `ServiceTest` will remain constant, the use of a proxy will divert the method calls to a new instance of `ModelTest`, created by Spring, per request.

Comment: This is your problem: `new ModelTest().toString()`. You are calling `new` directly, and thus `ModelTest` is not a Spring bean. The `@Value` annotation does nothing.

Comment: I am sorry I didnt get you. Here Object is getting created using new. It called constuctor along with @postconstruct method and finally toString method will call.

Comment: Assuming you want a new `ModelTest` instance per request, add `@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)`. This tells Spring to create a new `ModelTest` instance when starting processing a new request. Then, with `@Autowire` specify `ModelTest` as a field and return the value instead of calling `new`. The proxy allows one value to represent multiple requests.

Comment: You are using `new` to create `ModelTest`. Therefore Spring is not involved at all with `ModelTest`. Thus `@Value` in `ModelTest` has no meaning.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it :

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:myproperties.properties") // <-Add this.
class ModelTest {

     @Autowired
     private Environment env; 

     public void test(){
        String name = env.getProperty("name"); //Assuming you have a 'name' key in your myproperties.property
     }
}
```

Comment: Environment Object is empty. So it is throwing Null Exception

Comment: Something is not right here. You have `Autowired` the Environment object, and your `ModelTest` class is annotated with `@Component` .When the app launches, the IOC container WILL initialize these classes .I just tried it again and it is working for me .I hope you are importing the 'right' Environment class. `import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
`

Comment: Okey I am working on it, why Environment variable is getting empty. Have u checked with @value attribute in model class?